# What does the Save Game option do?

Tags: dead-rising-3

In Dead Rising 3, what does "Save Game" in the menu for normal mode actually do?

It appears to have no effect on anything!  Please be detailed in your answer, as it seems I am missing something.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Save Game option saves the game, but the automatic checkpoints in Story Mode make this mostly unnecessary.**

Since Story Mode auto-saves, the ability to save manually is of little value. The locations of toilet save points should be noted for if you move to Nightmare mode, and the auto-save and save-everywhere features are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a game loaded, you can  either select save game or say "Save Game" if your kinect is plugged in.    You should then see a prompt saying, "Game Saved successfully" - *Meaning that the game saved.*

See below:

[image]

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Answer (score -2):

Saving mode does not work it just goes back to the chapter no matter where you save the game